# Get request with parameters as string from URLRequest in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

Example of code:

```
var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();  
variables.var1 = 123;
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest('http://testdomain.com/api');
req.data = variables;
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.load(req);
```

Okay, loader has executed request: `http://testdomain.com/api?var1=123`.
How can I save this request to string? `req` has url and variables but as separated data.

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: Is this what you need? `req.url+'?'+req.data`

Comment: It's good to close the question if you've found the answer, which I think you did :) @null.point3r - you could write it as an answer so he can close the question..

Comment: @AndreyPopov You're right. If he'll write an answer, I'll close question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just concatenate `.url` and `.data` property of the request object:

```
var str:String=req.url+'?'+req.data;
```